# iOS: Calculate how long an enterprise signed app will work

Tags: ios, digital-signature, ipa

If you sign iOS app with your developer/enterprise certificate they will work for a certain period of time before suddenly iOS tells you `<appname> is no longer available`.

How do you calculate the date when an app expires and iOS refuses to open it?

For getting the expiration date I manually changed the system date of a test device to future dates and by multiple tests I found out that my app expires on 2024-04-12.

Then I checked all the dates contained in the signature of the main binary:

- Signer certificate dates:

  - notBefore 2022-05-05
  - notAfter 2023-05-05
- Signature time stamp:

  - signingTime 2022-09-26

So there is no match or another date that is the expiration date - multiple months.

Second I loaded the contained `embedded.mobileprovision` into the [Online ASN.1 viewer](https://lapo.it/asn1js/) which allows you to see all the certificate and signing dates.

- signingTime 2022-08-22

Again no match.

So the question remains, if I have an IPA file what file(s) do I need to parse to determine the date (and time) when iOS will refuse to load this the app from the IPA file?

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise distribution provisioning profiles expire [12 months after they are issued](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/deployment/depce7cefc4d/web)

> Distribution provisioning profiles expire 12 months after they’re issued. After the expiration date, the profile is removed and the app won’t launch.

However, your enterprise distribution certificate also needs to be valid for your app to launch:

> If your distribution certificate expires, the app won’t launch and you’ll need to rebuild the app with a new distribution certificate. Your distribution certificate is valid for three years from when it was issued or until your Apple Developer Enterprise Program membership expires, whichever comes first. To keep your certificate from expiring, be sure to renew your membership before it expires.

My guess would be your enterprise program renewal date is around the 12th of April next year. As long as you renew your enterprise program before that date your app will keep working until 12 months after the distribution provisioning profile was created.

Note that the device needs to be able to checkin in with the Apple OSCP server every 3 to 7 days. If it has no Internet connectivity for an extended period the app will no longer launch until the OSCP server can be checked.

Comment: The  enterprise program renewal date is in September, again a non-matching date... And shouldn't manipulating the system data also affect the OCSP check process (the device was offline when I changed system date)?

Comment: Apple had a really good session at WWDC about 8 or so years ago that explained how enterprise distribution certificates worked, but it no longer seems to be available. 

The other possibility is that one of Apples certificates  expires around April next year so validation fails but it won't when that date is reached because apple will have reissued it by then.

Comment: As a rule of thumb you should plan to update your enterprise app at least once per year.

Comment: [this session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/304/?time=540) has some detail, but not as much as the older session did. I think this is because Apple is really discouraging enterprise programs in favour of custom app distribution and unlisted app distribution